# Autoclick html button from Java in Android

Tags: java, android, jquery

I am writing an App in Eclipse for Android. The App constantly communicates with contents in a Web Server. In the Server, I have a html file which has another button. I wish that When I press the button in my Android App, the button in the html file is autoclicked..Is it possible. Please suggest..

I see that with the below code(jquery):

```
$(".press").trigger('click');
```

autoclick of html button is achieved but how do i do that from java in android..?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

just use javascript:

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        yourWebView.loadUrl("javascript:clickHtmlButton()");
    }
});
```

javascript:

```
function clickHtmlButton(){
   $(".press").click();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but i am not using webview here. Webview will open a webbrowser.. I donot want that

Comment: can you explain better your environment?